# How to find the cases in the top n percentile of several variables at the same time?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Imagine we have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(10, 20), y = seq(8, 18), z = seq(0, 10))

    x  y  z
1  10  8  0
2  11  9  1
3  12 10  2
4  13 11  3
5  14 12  4
6  15 13  5
7  16 14  6
8  17 15  7
9  18 16  8
10 19 17  9
11 20 18 10
```

How can we select the cases the are in the HIGHEST percentile on all X, Y and Z? I need a code that searches for cases in the top 1% on all variables, then if it finds nothing, loosens up the criterion to 2%, then 3% and so on until it finds m cases that is in the highest percentile on all the variables. We need to set m as we desire.

Comment: So you want to select rows where all three of x y and z are in the top nth percentile, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. But I need to be able to select the number of rows that will be selected. I don't care what n will be.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for you:

```
df<-data.frame(x=seq(10,20), y=seq(8,18), z=seq(0,10))

#defining function - df is input frame, cases is the 'm' you are looking for
#startingperc is just the percentage level you want to start with and tickrate
#is the rate at which you decrease the perentile until you get m cases
myfunc <- function(df, cases, startingperc, tickrate){
  found <- 0
  while(found < cases) {
    quants <- apply(df, 2, quantile, probs = startingperc)
    indices <- which(apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x > quants)) == TRUE)
    found <- length(indices)
    if(found < cases) {startingperc <- startingperc - tickrate}
  }
  #added this to handle a tickrate that is too large
  if (length(indices) > cases) {
    indices <- rev(indices[order(apply(df[indices,],1, sum), decreasing = T)[1:cases]])
  }
  return(df[indices,])
}

#in use
myfunc(df, 5, .99, .01)
```

Giving:

```
> myfunc(df, 5, .99, .01)
    x  y  z
7  16 14  6
8  17 15  7
9  18 16  8
10 19 17  9
11 20 18 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to know how many observation are there in what sequences of quantiles. You could modify this function to get the indices of those rows as well. Also you could change the the iteration index for quantiles.

```
lapply(lapply(seq(0.9,0.1,-0.1), function(xx) Reduce(intersect, lapply(df, function(x) which(x>=quantile(x, probs = xx))))), length)
```

This check for obs where values is greater that quantile and then does an intersection with all the columns to get the common indices. I then feed a vector of quantile which is iterated. Then i simple calculate the length.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not strictly speaking necessary (you could just look for the minimum percentiles and use `ceiling`), this is a nice case for a recursive function:

```
fun <- function(n_rows = 1, pct = 1, dat = df){
    # This part doesn't need to be repeated. Uses dplyr::percent_rank to calculate 
    # percentiles, and sums each row of percentiles.
    row_sums <- rowSums(matrix(1 - dplyr::percent_rank(dat), 
                               ncol = ncol(dat)))
    fun2 <- function(p = pct){    # defines a recursive function
        # calculates if each row is below percentile threshold
        working_rows <- row_sums <= p / 100 * ncol(dat)
        if(sum(working_rows) >= n_rows){    # if enough rows,
            dat[working_rows, ]    # returns them
        } else {
            fun2(p + 1)    # else calls itself, incrementing the threshold
        }
    }
    fun2(pct)    # call recursive function with initial percentile
}

fun()
##     x  y  z
## 11 20 18 10

fun(3)
##     x  y  z
## 9  18 16  8
## 10 19 17  9
## 11 20 18 10

fun(n_rows = 1, pct = 50)
##     x  y  z
## 7  16 14  6
## 8  17 15  7
## 9  18 16  8
## 10 19 17  9
## 11 20 18 10
```

Note this ranks all the values across columns in a single group. To rank each column individually, replace the `row_sums` line with just

```
row_sums <- rowSums(sapply(dat, dplyr::percent_rank))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for finding columnwise percentile membership and use it :

```
df<-data.frame(x=100:900, y=1100: 1900, z=2800:2000) 
tail(df)    
# percentile membership of a column    

getPercentile<- function (datacol) 
{
    as.numeric(cut(datacol, breaks = quantile(datacol, probs = seq(0, 
        1, by = 0.01)), labels = as.character(1:100), include.lowest = TRUE))
}

getPercentile(df$x)

#get columwise percentile membership of all columns
res<- as.data.frame(apply( df,2,getPercentile ))

colnames(res)

#filter any way you want 
# bottom 2 % of first two and top 90% of last 
res[res$x<=2 & res$y<=2 & res$z>=90, ]
```